# Space leak with redundant use of seq in GHC interpreter

Tags: haskell, ghc, space-leak

I type this code into the interpreter and memory is rapidly consumed:

```
last [1..10^7] `seq` ()
```

I can't see why this needs more than O(1) space. If i do just (which should be the same, because Show forces weak head normal form, so seq is redundant?):

```
last [1..10^7]
```

...it works fine.

I'm unable to reproduce this situation outside the interpreter.

What's going on here?

---

Here are some test cases:
http://hpaste.org/69234

Things to note:

- By running in the interpreter, I load wtf.hs without compiling it, and type `wtf<n>` in ghci.
- By compiling, I do `ghc --make wtf.hs && ./wtf`.
- `last` can be substituted for a `sum` with strict accumulator or a function that finds the max element in the list, and the space leak still happens
- I haven't seen this behaviour when using `$!` instead of `seq`.
- I tried adding a dummy `()` parameter because I thought maybe this is a CAF problem. Changes nothing.
- It's probably not a problem with functions on `Enum`, because I can reproduce the behaviour with `wtf5` and later, which don't use `Enum` at all.
- It's probably not a problem with `Num`, `Int`, or `Integer`, because I can reproduce the behaviour without them in `wtf14` and `wtf16`.

I tried reproducing the problem with Peano arithmetic to take lists and integers out of the equation (fetching the at the end of of 10^9), but ran into other sharing/space leak problems I don't understand when trying to implement `*`.

Comment: Could it have something to do with [extended default rules](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html#extended-default-rules)?

Comment: @ChrisWong well, if type-defaulting was the culprit, fixing the types such as `seq (last [1::Int ..10^8]) ()` should have fixed that...

Comment: I tried the example with different infinite lists. With `repeat 1` there's no space leak, with `[1,1..]` there is. Perhaps the arithmetic of `enumFrom` and friends is somehow responsible?

Comment: @n.m. That's because the infinite list produced by `repeat` takes constant space due to sharing. If you try `map id (repeat 1)` to sabotage the sharing, it leaks again.

Comment: While `last (map id (repeat 1)) ^seq^ ()` will leak, `last (map id (repeat ())) ^seq^ ()` wont. Yet `last (map id (repeat Wtf)) ^seq^ ()` where `data Wtf = Wtf` will. (replace ^ with backtick)

Answer (score 15):

We need to look at the instance of `enumFromTo` for Integer, and last:

```
last []                 =  errorEmptyList "last"
last (x:xs)             =  last' x xs
  where last' y []     = y
        last' _ (y:ys) = last' y ys
```

It is defined in GHC.Enum as:

```
enumFrom x             = enumDeltaInteger  x 1
enumFromThen x y       = enumDeltaInteger  x (y-x)
enumFromTo x lim       = enumDeltaToInteger x 1 lim
```

where

```
enumDeltaInteger :: Integer -> Integer -> [Integer]
enumDeltaInteger x d = x `seq` (x : enumDeltaInteger (x+d) d)
-- strict accumulator, so
--     head (drop 1000000 [1 .. ]
-- works
```

and

```
enumDeltaToInteger :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> [Integer]
enumDeltaToInteger x delta lim
  | delta >= 0 = up_list x delta lim
  | otherwise  = dn_list x delta lim

up_list :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> [Integer]
up_list x0 delta lim = go (x0 :: Integer)
                where
                    go x | x > lim   = []
                         | otherwise = x : go (x+delta)
```

`last` is fully lazy, as expected.

For the Integer Enum class, we have a strict accumulator (explicitly) for `enumFrom`. In the bounded case (e.g. `[1..n]`), it calls `enumDeltaToInteger` and then into `up_list`, which uses a worker to unfold a list until its limit is reached.

But `up_list` is strict in `x` in the `go` helper (see the comparison against `lim`).

When run in GHCi none of this is optimized, yielding naive calls to enumFromTo, before returning `()`.

```
let
  it_ax6 :: ()      
  it_ax6 =
    case last
           @ GHC.Integer.Type.Integer
           (GHC.Enum.enumFromTo
              @ GHC.Integer.Type.Integer
              GHC.Num.$fEnumInteger
              (GHC.Integer.smallInteger 1)
              (GHC.Real.^
                 @ GHC.Integer.Type.Integer
                 @ GHC.Integer.Type.Integer
                 GHC.Num.$fNumInteger
                 GHC.Real.$fIntegralInteger
                 (GHC.Integer.smallInteger 10)
                 (GHC.Integer.smallInteger 7)))
    of _ -> GHC.Unit.()
in
  GHC.Base.thenIO
    @ ()
    @ [()]
    (System.IO.print @ () GHC.Show.$fShow() it_ax6)
    (GHC.Base.returnIO
       @ [()] (GHC.Types.: @ () it_ax6 (GHC.Types.[] @ ())))
```

So, why are we retaining the list in the `seq` case, and not in the regular case? The regular case runs nicely in constrant space, relying on the laziness of `enumFromTo` for `Integer` and for `last`. The GHCi core for that case looks like:

```
let {
  it_aKj :: GHC.Integer.Type.Integer
  [LclId,
   Unf=Unf{Src=<vanilla>, TopLvl=False, Arity=0, Value=False,
           ConLike=False, Cheap=False, Expandable=False,
           Guidance=IF_ARGS [] 170 0}]
  it_aKj =
    GHC.List.last
      @ GHC.Integer.Type.Integer
      (GHC.Enum.enumFromTo
         @ GHC.Integer.Type.Integer
         GHC.Num.$fEnumInteger
         (GHC.Integer.smallInteger 1)
         (GHC.Real.^
            @ GHC.Integer.Type.Integer
            @ GHC.Integer.Type.Integer
            GHC.Num.$fNumInteger
            GHC.Real.$fIntegralInteger
            (GHC.Integer.smallInteger 10)
            (GHC.Integer.smallInteger 7))) } in
GHC.Base.thenIO
  @ ()
  @ [()]
  (System.IO.print
     @ GHC.Integer.Type.Integer GHC.Num.$fShowInteger it_aKj)
  (GHC.Base.returnIO
     @ [()]
     (GHC.Types.:
        @ ()
        (it_aKj
         `cast` (UnsafeCo GHC.Integer.Type.Integer ()
                 :: GHC.Integer.Type.Integer ~ ()))
        (GHC.Types.[] @ ())))
```

So these are almost identical, with the differences being:

- in the `seq` version, `last (enumFromTo ..)` is forced inside a `case`.
- in the regular version, it is a lazy `let`.
- in the `seq` version, the value is computed then discarded, yielding a `()` -- nothing looks at the result
- in the regular case, it is inspected and shown.

What is odd is that there's nothing magic about:

```
let x = case last (enumFromTo 1 n) of _ -> ()
```

that makes it retain values.

As we see, the implementation of `up_list` is strict in its accumulator (since it compares against `lim`, and the list is unfolded lazily -- so `last` should be able to consume it in constant space). Writing the expression by hand confirms this.

Doing a heap profile of the ghci execution shows the entire list being retained:

[image]

which tells us at least that it isn't a chain of thunks, but rather, the entire list is being built strictly and held on to, until being discarded.

So the mystery is: what is holding onto the list argument to `last` in ghci, and not in ghc?

I suspect some internal (or subtle) detail of ghci now -- I think this is worth a ghci ticket.

Comment: I don't think enum or integers have anything to do with it at all. The thing is I'm not sure how Haskell is supposed to work in any case so it's hard for me to report a bug.

Comment: Maybe try ghci with -frewrite-rules ?

Answer (score 1):

I think @n.m is right.
Nothing is forcing the *value* in the list, so the 1+1+1+1+... thunk eventually kills space.

I will whip up a quick test.

Comment: seq just requires it's left argument to be in WHNF. Logically, I would expect that, if demanding the result of `seq (last [1..10^9]) x`* is a space leak, so would be anything that demands the result of `last [1..10^9]` (which is not the case). *sorry about writing my stuff differently than in the discussion above, this markdown tripe prevents me from using backticks.

Comment: I tried the same element-strict strategy as enumDeltaInteger and it did nothing in ghci.  So I am guessing ghci is being dumb.  Perhaps even buggy.

Comment: It would have to force the value to calculate if it had reached the upper bound yet or not, so I don't think this is a likely explanation.